# Error with triangulation using cv.triangulatePoints()

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, triangulation, stereo-3d

I am trying to find the corresponding 3d point from two images using the openCV function triangulatePoints() in python. It takes as input the two Projection matrices of both cameras and 2 corresponding image point coordinates (i have all four of thes inputs). --> cv.triangulatePoints(projMatr1, projMatr2, projPoints1, projPoints2).

However, i can't seem to figure out in which form the 2 image point coordinates should be. I've looked up documentation which says :

projPoints1 2xN array of feature points in the first image. It can be also a cell array of feature points {[x,y], ...} or two-channel array of size 1xNx2 or Nx1x2.

However I try to use these coordinates as an input, i always get an error. Does anyone know how i should input these?

Comment: A 2xN numpy array does work, as the documentation suggests, e.g: ```A = np.eye(3,4); pts = np.zeros([2,10]); cv2.triangulatePoints(A,A,pts,pts);``` What kind of error are you seeing?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i was able to get rid of the errors. However, i still don't really understand how the coordinates are given as input using a 2XN array. Using your example of a 2X10 numpy array, does this simply mean your giving 10 different image coordinates, as such :

[[ x1 x1 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10]
[y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8 y9 y10]]

where for example (x1,y1) is one coordinate, and the function triangulatePoints then gives 10 different 3D coordinates back ?